# wamp server locally denied?

Tags: wampserver, http-status-code-403

I have just installed Wamp Server 2 to my pc. and I cannot access phpmyadmin, or even index.php at root directory, it all gives 403 Forbidden.

I have also tried to change permission from alias.conf it did not work.

Do you have any idea how to solve this, or any offer is worth to try, please share.

Thanks in advance.

PS: OS: W7, antivirus KasperSky, windows firewall off.

EDIT: restarting wamp solved phpmyadmin access but directory access (ie: `http://localhost/index.php`) is still forbidden.

EDIT2: I can now access my index.php through the url: `127.0.0.1/index.php` but I cannot still access `http://localhost/index.php` and I shall use `http://localhost/`

EDIT3: Logs are full of :

```
[Fri Apr 13 20:50:06 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/
[Fri Apr 13 20:50:19 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my old guide here, many of my friend has this error and this guide works http://www.hieule.info/site/web/solve-the-denied-access-problem-when-using-wamp-server-2-on-windows-8- Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Please place the solution here rather than providing a (spammy) link to your website.

Answer (score 2):

I'm planning to use wampserver on windows 8 to run a local only server. I fixed this problem by editing Apache httpd.conf like Trung-Hieu Le (cf.), but only changed one line :

Change

```
Listen 80
```

To

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
#Listen 80
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem with apache configuration. Go to httpd.cong file and replace line number 46 to Listen 127.0.0.1:80. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a firewall problem, you wouldn't even get a 403 error, you'd just get "site is unreachable" from your browser. Check the server error log, it'll explain exactly why it you're getting the error.

I'm guessing it's due to a mis-configured default document with directory browsing disabled - e.g. you've got an index.php in there, but Apache's only looking for index.html by default. With directory browser disabled, you'll get a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: logs are full of 

[Fri Apr 13 20:50:06 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/
[Fri Apr 13 20:50:19 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/

Comment: there you go, it's an apache configuration. Now you just have to figure out why. Given the ::1 address on your client there, make sure that your site's IPv6 configuration is the same as for IPv4.

Comment: I dont have any IPv4 or IPv6 configuration. can you guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

chnage localhost to 127.0.0.1 and should work , i had smiler problem :)

```
::1 - - [11/Nov/2012:14:29:34 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Nov/2012:14:29:37 +0330] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6051
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts
add a new line with: 127.0.0.1 localhost

Answer (score 0):

I had that error and it was caused by having inadvertently deleted the C:\Wamp\Apps folder.  Tripped me up because I would have expected a 404 in that case, not a 403.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and most effective sollution in my case and to what I suppose in most of the other cases is all about the access:-

Just follow the following simple step:-

Just Open your httpd.conf file, over there you will see the following

onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

Just Change the Deny from All with Allow from All and save the changes and restart all your services in the Wamp server

(Change above with the following)
onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

No need to change your port or anything else.

Simple and 100% effective

Hope it help others aswell