# 403 Apache error Forbidden You don't have permission to access /clientServerTest/ on this server

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to connect to my wampserver 2.4 online but I have the following error:
`Forbidden You don't have permission to access /clientServerTest/ on this server.`
The error log shows:

```
[Sun Jun 08 21:53:45.281433 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 6696:tid 1492] [client 192.168.0.7:52659] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
```

I have browsed a while and looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975560/apache-403-error-except-from-localhost) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145739/wamp-server-locally-denied) but no luck so far.
The server is `already online` and I can access it just fine using `localhost`. However, when I try to connect to it using the `ipv4` of my pc on my local network I got the error.

I am using windows 7.

The firewall is already off.

Can anybody please help me out on this?

Comment: click on Wamp -> Put Online if you try to access the server remote . or try to access the server with http://127.0.0.1/ instead of http://localhost/ to see if works

Comment: Yeah I have done that, sorry maybe the question wasn't clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to do

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
Require ip 192.168.0
```

Or whatever the first 3 quartiles of your local subnet is.
This uses the Apache 2.4 syntax rather than the Apache 2.2 syntax, and gives access to all the possible localhost variants and the local network, but not the world.

This way when you decide to open up your router you wont accidentally allow acccess to the world to all your development sites.

You will have to do this to all 3 app configs in the alias folder.

Comment: thank! I'll test it later! So far what I am doing  is just a personal project to practice

Comment: Of course, but best to practice the right way rather than the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... apparently I am found what was wrong...
In the `httpd.config` file in the following snippet (can access from the wamp menu):

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

I removed `Deny form all` and put in `Allow from all` so now it looks like:

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

Not sure it is the right solution... but at least I can connect